# Replace punctuation marks in strings with spaces

Tags: string-manipulation

I have a list of strings. Some of them contain commas, single quotes, etc. Is there a quick way to replace those characters by blanks? My list looks something like this:

```
list = {"string1", "bla,bla", "more'stuff", "and more;stuff"}
```

cheers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use

```
StringReplace[list, PunctuationCharacter -> " "]

(* {"string1", "bla bla", "more stuff", "and more stuff"} *)
```

[`PunctuationCharacter`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PunctuationCharacter.html) is new in version 10.3.  The 10.x updates received many new functions for text processing.  In older versions I would use an explicit list of possible punctuation characters, i.e.

```
punctuation = Alternatives@@Characters[",.?:;'\"!-"]
```

I'm pretty sure I missed some.

```
StringReplace[list, punctuation -> " "]
(* {"string1", "bla bla", "more stuff", "and more stuff"} *)
```

Comment: What is `PunctuationCharacter` ?

Comment: @eldo I updated the answer.

Comment: ...and of course, regex: `StringReplace[list, RegularExpression["[[:punct:]]"] -> " "]`.